# How can I add a polynomial regression in R on a qplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, statistics, regression

I am creating a histogram for my itunes library, length of song (seconds), vs frequency. The graph is coming out nicely, but I can't plot a regression line over it without an error being returned.

```
    qplot(v10, xlab = "Length", ylab = "Frequency",
    main = "Length of Songs In my library", binwidth = 1, bins = 100 )
```

This returns a nice plot, when I add

```
    +  geom_smooth(method='lm + x^2')
```

I get errors. I have tried variations to get a regression line, all of them failing. I am thinking it might have something to do with my Y values being a frequency of x, and not having a column of its own in the data frame.

Comment: please create a reproducable example for your question, refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Try using `method = 'lm', formula = 'whatever formula'` instead.

Comment: inside of the geom_smooth, or qplot? and what do you mean by 'whatever formula'...?

Comment: `+ stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula=y~x+I(x^2))` or `formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)`